# why byte += 1 compile but byte = byte + 1 not?

Tags: java, types

If I have a byte variable: `byte b = 0;`

why does the following work:

```
   b++;
   b += 1; // compiles
```

... but this does not ?

```
   b = b + 1; // compile error
```

Does compiler understand first as `byte` and second as `int` ?

**[EDIT]**

I know casting but I want to draw your attention to the `b++, b += 1 and b = b + 1`

I think they are equal so why compiler differs them ? what is the difference between

```
  b += 1 and b = b + 1 ?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81392/java-why-do-i-receive-the-error-message-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-int-to-by has your answer

Comment: nothing to laugh at :) the + operator practically ensures the int part

Comment: for the edit part:  `byte b=0; b+=333;` this is ok. b+=1 is compiled like b=(byte)(b+1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `b += 1` is an equivalent to `b = (byte)(b + 1)`, whereas type of `b + 1` is promoted to `int` ([JLS §5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#170983)) and therefore its result cannot be assigned to `byte` without explicit conversion.

From [JLS, §15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Comment: Is there a way to write a numeric constant so that it is viewed as a byte?  If I write 7F it is viewed as a float, 7L is a long and so on.  Would something like 7B be viewed as a byte?

Comment: @BigMac66, `static final byte C1 = 11;// this is a byte` but still adding C1+C1 is not a byte, yet `static final byte C2 = C1 + C1;` is correct (b/c it's calculated by the compiler not the runtime), remove `final`  from C1 and it's an error.

Comment: I get that, what I am asking is when you write a primitive constant value you can append a letter to designate the type you intend that constant to be, is there a letter for the byte primitive?  So far I can only find L (long), D (double) and F (float) - are there any others?

Comment: @BigMac66: There are no other suffixes, and perhaps there is no need in them, since compile-time constants of type 'int' can be converted to narrower types implicitly when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Possible loss of precision is the problem. Cast it and it is OK.

```
b = (byte) (b + 1);
```

Comment: The answer is correct but I still don’t like the explanation. If possible loss of precision were a valid reason here, then the same should be prohibited for integers. After all, `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` has the same (or a similar) problem.

Comment: You are right. The compiler protects you better with bytes than integers: b = 127; is OK for the compiler, while b = 128; is not and must be casted before it gives you a -128 value which is correct. Not so with integers. On the other hand you can say        int i = 2147483647; which is Integer.MAX_VALUE and if you go up by one int i = 2147483648; you do get a compiler error "integer number too large". I think axtavt explains the situation well. With the byte we have a promotion with the int not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the result of the `+`-operation is `int`, so a cast is needed in order to assign it to a `byte` variable.

Answer (score 2):

In java the default for integers is int, and for floating point numbers it is double. So `b` is by default converted to integer to perform the operation. So the resultant answer needs to be typecasted before being stored to prevent any possible loss of precision. But `b+=1` does it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

operands of type byte and short are automatically promoted to int before being handed to the operators

so when you do byte b= b + 1;
it considers it "int" as an operation is performed on byte value. so to avoid this we use b+=1; here it is automatically typecasted to byte.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to byte:

```
b = (byte) (b + 1);
```

Comment: edited. I know that casting solve this problem but I want to learn other thing that written in editted part

Answer (score 0):

Doing `b + 1` widens the result to integer, and assigning back to byte b would cause loss of precision. Explained: [Conversions and Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html). But I like axtavt's answer better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't buy the argument about loss of precision, since the compiler won't protect you in a similar fashion when dealing with ints and longs.
I think the real answer lies with the JLS simply having better support for ints than bytes, as stated in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13211737/567000