# Java (Implicit type casting): Does a unary operator affect the data type of the variables in operation?

Tags: java, types, casting

While learning about implicit and explicit type casting, I tried the following code:

```
class Implicit
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        byte a=10;
        byte b=20;

        a=a+b; //

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

The compiler reports:

[image]

I tried this code to see if a unary operator or any other operation in such example can cause the data type on the Right Hand Side to change.

Is this what is happening here? If so, what is the reason? What other situations would cause the data type to be altered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler warns you because `byte+byte = int` Thus, it warns you when to try to add two bytes(essentially an int after the addition) and assign it to an byte, which would lead to loss of precision, as byte can only hold 8 bits where as an int can hold 32 bits.

However, this would not give you a warning when you use [**compound assignment operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2).

```
    a+=b; //
```

Comment: Nota bene: `byte` barely exists on the JVM level.

Answer (score 1):

It warns your

> possible loss of precision

because the addition operator causes each of the `byte` values to be promoted to an `int` before the addition is done (Binary Numeric Promotion). So byte+byte would be an `int` result and to assign back to a byte `a` it needs to downcast `int` to `byte`. The downcast may result in loss of precision if the value of the addition is greater than can be stored as a `byte` value.

You can force compiler to accept this by explicitly downcast as `a=(byte)(a+b)` where signals that you know the risk and compiler shouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

the add operations cause the byte variable to be promoted to int.

see the answer to this question [Add bytes with type casting, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815970/add-bytes-with-type-casting-java)

i dont quite know why with java, but it seems for c#(yes, c# have similar result), it's for performance sake. See here for details [byte + byte = int... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)