# Java byte to int Coercion

Tags: java, coercion

I have a question about the code below. The code is taken from my Programming Languages book.

```
byte x, y, z;
...
/* The values of y and z are coerced into int and int addition is performed */
/* The sum is converted into byte */
x = y + z;
```

My question is why Java does a coercion like that. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The obtainable answer is that the JLS says so.

Comment: It's because that's how the JVM works (it can't do addition on bytes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483470/is-addition-of-byte-converts-to-int-is-because-of-java-language-rules-or-because

Comment: I understand that y and z become ints during addition, but doesn't setting this back to x cause a compile error without a cast?

Comment: @whiskeyspider Yes it will.

Comment: This page contains very useful information regarding this issue: https://www.artima.com/underthehood/bytecodeP.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JVM, every stack element has a size of 32 bits. The actual addition works like this:

1. The two bytes are pushed on the stack as 32bit values (therefore they are `int`)
2. The `iadd` instruction is called, which pops two values from the stack and adds them
3. The resulting integer is pushed on the stack again

This is why you have to cast the resulting value (of type `int`) to a `byte` again.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the JVM instruction set simple, it doesn't implement an addition operator for each integral type. Specifically, it can't add bytes. (See [the list of JVM ops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1)) This makes the JVM simpler, and probably more portable.

Comment: and what about longs (onx64) ?

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev, Misspoke. Fixed.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev there is an instruction for adding longs (ladd), which pops four 32bit values (2 for each number) from the stack, adds them, and pushes two 32 bit values onto the stack again.

Comment: @ikegami Nice to see you on Java tag :) You can add this [JVM Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1) link to your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

This mirrors the java byte code, the jvm, java virtual machine, that in the specification uses an int to store a single byte variable on the stack. It uses `iadd` for adding two bytes. See the [jvm instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

One might argue that it is a bit of overspecification: mentioning an implementation choice of the reference implementation.