# cannot convert from int to byte

Tags: java, casting, integer, byte

I have a rather simple - but for me confusing - question.
Assume the byte variabels a,b,c:

```
byte a = 5;
byte b = 3;
byte c = a + b; // wont compile
```

Line 3 wont compile because - I suppose - Java has to make a calculation behind the scenes and the outcome of the calculation is an integer. An integer can't be passed to a byte without explicit casting. So (byte)(a+b) should have been provided. But now assume there is a 4th line of code with an explicit cast to integer ...

```
c = (int) 8 ; // compiles
```

It *compiles although the byte variabel 'c' is explicitly casted to integer*. How is Java handling this aspect ... ?

Comment: Bytes have their own operators. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm and they are not integers.

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before. Have a look [here][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483470/is-addition-of-byte-converts-to-int-is-because-of-java-language-rules-or-because

Comment: Try `c=(int)128` and you might know the difference yourself !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are failing to see is that `a+b` is a *run-time* operation whereas `byte b = (int)8;` is a *compile-time* operation. SO, during compile-time, the compiler knows that the constant `8` can be fit in a byte. So, the explicit conversion to `(int)` is *ignored*. The byte code will have not difference with or without the `(int)`.

Now, in the first case if both byte variables were `final` (i.e, constant), then the compiler would have allowed this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final byte a = 5; // constant
    final byte b = 3; // constant
    byte c = a + b; // WILL compile;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Line 3 wont compile because - I suppose - Java has to make a calculation behind the scenes and the outcome of the calculation is an integer.

Correct.

> But now assume there is a 4th line of code with an explicit cast to integer
>
> ```
> c = (int) 8 ; // compiles
> ```
>
> It compiles although the byte variabel 'c' is explicitly casted to integer.

Because you used a literal value, `8`, and the compiler knows `8` will fit in `byte`.

A better comparison would be:

```
c = (int)b;
```

...which fails.

Answer (score 0):

The point is byte is of 8 bits and int is 32 bits integer value. So for instance, when you add two byte numbers under 127 then that can add to a result which is over 127 which is out of the range of byte, and by default Java uses int for almost all numbers.

The [JVM doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1) says:

> A compiler encodes loads of literal values of types byte and short using Java Virtual Machine instructions that sign-extend those values to values of type int at compile-time or run-time. Loads of literal values of types boolean and char are encoded using instructions that zero-extend the literal to a value of type int at compile-time or run-time. [..]. Thus, most operations on values of actual types boolean, byte, char, and short are correctly performed by instructions operating on values of computational type int.