# Java: Byte addition, why does b += 1 work but b = b + 1 is converted into integer?

Tags: java

Went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483470/is-addition-of-byte-converts-to-int-is-because-of-java-language-rules-or-because) StackOverflow answer explaining how java converts all `boolean`, `byte`, `char` and `short` data types into `int` .

This does not explain whyin `byte b`, `b += 1` works but `b = b + 1` throws an error, even `b = b + (byte)1` and `b = (byte)b + (byte)1` throws the same error.

Comment: I think you have to use `b = (byte)(b+1)` instead of `b = (byte)b + (byte)1` to prevent the error. (also please specify in the question that `b` is a `byte`)

Comment: You need to do `b = (byte)(b + 1);` to mimic `b += 1;`

Comment: but why does b = b + 1 not work and b += 1 does?