# How to fix this error : incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Tags: java

I perfectly write my java code but this  ERROR (internal.java:21: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte) bringing repeatedly. but a,b,c variables are byte data type. So please help by solve this problem. And why this problem bringing me. please explain this problem technically.

I already use type conversion such as a=(byte)(c+b) and it's work. But why this error comes. So please explain this error.

class Inter
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    byte a = 20 , b = 10, c = 20 ;

    if(a<=b && a<=c)
    {
        a = c+b;

        System.out.println(a);
    }
    else if(b>=c)
    {
        a +=b;

        System.out.println(a);
    }

    else 
    {
        a+=c;

        System.out.println(a);
    }



    float t = (a/40.0f)*10;

    System.out.println("internal mark is : "+ t);
}
```

}

internal.java:21: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
            a = (byte)c+b;
                       ^
1 error

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483470/is-addition-of-byte-converts-to-int-because-of-java-language-rules-or-because-of

Answer (score 0):

`byte` in java is **8 bit** size, which has a limit of **-128 to 127**. So suppose a scenario like if **a = 127 and b = 127**. So if you **add a and b the value is 254**, which `byte` data type can not hold.

So when you add two `byte` type variable, output is automatically converted to `int`. So it should be assigned by `int`.

So assigning the output of a+b to a byte by implicit casting, will overflow and results won't be correct.

Comment: this is compile time error and i am not give the any value in a,b and c variables in code

Comment: Yes, it will give compile time error. As compiler don't know what value will be assigned to a and b at runtime. So always addition of two byte type variables always gives output as int by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In Java a byte can hold values ranging from -128 to 127, if you have passed values more than 127 which will cause the byte to overflow and can't hold it so it will cause into the exception, but when you are casting the addition or larger value than 127 to byte it will try to get the negative range value -128 and from there it goes on repetitive, like if byte a=10; and byte b=120; then byte c=(byte)(a+b); will return you -126 as it is 3 numbers more than 127, now it goes to -128,-127 and -126 value will be taken. So to get this value loss fixed compiler will force you to take c as int so that there will be no loss in the actual value which you wanted.