# Why this code is throwing error?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. So I am unable to understand the reason why this exception is occurring. Here is my code:

```
class St
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        byte b1,b2,b3;
        b1=10;
        b2=5;
        b3=b1+b2;
        System.out.println(b3);
    }
}
```

Please explain.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add bytes with type casting, Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815970/add-bytes-with-type-casting-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have an addition operator for bytes, so to compute `b1+b2` the values are converted to `int` and the sum is calculated as with ints. You get the error because there is no implicit conversion from int to byte because of possible loss of precision.

You have to use an implicit casting conversion to get the sum as `byte`:

```
b3=(byte)(b1+b2);
```

By the way, this is not an "exception" but a compile-time error. Exceptions are produced when you run a program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Cast` the result to `byte` because the binary operation in java should at least returns `int` value, So `byte+byte` is an `int` value, cast the result of two operands `b1` and `b2` to `byte` and assign it to `b3` which is `byte`:

```
b3=(byte)(b1+b2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`b1` + `b2` is automatically casted to `int` (the immediately greater primitive), because you could reach the maximum `byte` value, so you can't assign it to a `byte` without manually casting (which may result in undesired results). Try this instead.-

```
byte b1,b2;
int b3;
b1 = 10;
b2 = 5;
b3 = b1 + b2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of adding two `byte`s is an `int`. So, there's a potential **precision loss** here when you assign the `int` to a `byte`. That's what the compiler is warning you about. Hence, you need a cast `()` here to do it explicitly as

```
b3 = (byte) (b1+b2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add to byte values the result would be integer so if you are trying to add to bytes and assign it to byte the it gives you the castexception.So just type cast the value of the addtion to byte or take the result type as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

add cast to byte like this way `(byte)`

complete answer

```
class St
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        byte b1,b2,b3;
        b1=10;
        b2=5;
        b3=(byte) (b1+b2);
        System.out.println(b3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work after casting with byte.

```
b3=(byte) (b1+b2);
```

As `+` convers automatically into int.

It throws error like `Type mismatch:cannot convert from int to byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Straight forward, try this code:

```
public class st
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        byte b1,b2,b3;
        b1=10;
        b2=5;
        b3=(byte) (b1+b2);
        System.out.println(b3);
    }
}
```