# Java arithmetic operation and then casting

Tags: java

I have this piece of code.

```
        short x = 50,y=40;
        short z = (short)(x + y);//THIS COMPILES
        short z2 = (short) x + y;//THIS DOESN'T
```

How come the code snippet of z compiles, while z2 doesn't? When performing an arithmetic operation on short it will immediately promote it to a int. however I'm downcasting it back to short but it produces an error. Please explain. Am I missing anything?

Comment: First case you are downcasting the result of two integer additions, in the second case you are trying to assign an `int` + `short` to a `short` without casting. You're only casting the first argument to a `short`.

Comment: Check the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81392/java-why-do-i-receive-the-error-message-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-int-to-b). It applies to your case too.

Comment: `(short) x + y` is the same as `((int) (short) x) + (int) y`

Comment: short z2 = (short) x + (short) y;   //THIS also DOESN'T because of precendence.
First '+' and than is casting to short.

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
(short) x + y
```

Can be understood like this:

```
short + int
```

Because the type cast only applies for `x`, not for the result of the sum. So, the result of the operation returns an `int`, thus the compiler exception.

Comment: so, the casting is being done first before the arithmetic operation?

Answer (score 1):

The second line compiles, because the result of the addition is casted to a `short` so it can be assigned to `z`, a `short`.

The third line doesn't compile, because the cast to `short` only applies to `x`, before the addition takes place.  The result of the addition of a `short` and an `int` is an `int`, which can't be assigned directly to a `short` (`z2`).

The parentheses in the second line force the order of operations necessary for a `short` value to be assigned to a `short` variable.

Comment: How is it being evaluated? is it being evaluated from left to right? not the operations first?

Comment: The cast operator `()` has a higher [precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than the `+` operator, so the cast will operate first without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In the z you are casting the final outcome of x+y as a whole to a short and assigned it to a short.

But in the z2 you are casting x to a short and adding it with y gives a int. SO int can't be assigned to a short. That is why you get the compile error